# Analytic continuation of a p-adic power series

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Consider the power series $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1-x^p}}$ over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, defined by $f(0)=1$. Does it have an analytic continuation that converges on a disk of radius greater than 1? I am particuarly interested in the values for Teichmuller representatives $\lambda$, which satisfy $\lambda^q=\lambda$ for some $q=p^r$. Apparently they are related to classical results on Gauss Sums but I couldn't find anything in the literature.

Comment: I think I disagree, @OscarLanzi. What’s under the radical sign is just $\frac1{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{p-1}}$.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think your quest can not succeed. The square-root sign makes things all the worse, I think, but the function surely becomes infinite toward the primitive $p$-th roots of unity. But these are not Teichmüller representatives. Have you looked at the simple case $p=3$?